# Not able to remove image from superview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've created an animation that, when finished, is supposed to remove the image being animated. For some reason, it's not being working (i.e. it's not removing the image). Is there something I'm doing wrong?:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.8 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     appleView[i].frame = CGRectMake(applePosition, 400.0, 25.0, 25.0);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ [appleView[i] removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

Answer (score 1):

The possible reason is that `appleView[i]` is nil. Put a breakpoint inside completion block and check that.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code ..

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.8];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut forView:self.view cache:YES];
[appleView[i] removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

i hope this help you...

Comment: this is exactly the same thing, only it's using the old syntax instead of the block-based one, which by the way it's said to be preferred in the official documentation

Comment: yes but some time blocks not worked dude i tried every type of this animation if here may this code useful so just post dude.. Thanx dude.. :)

Comment: Actually I was using this same method before, and it does work! But I was hoping to try block-based after I heard it was preferred. If I can't figure it out, I'll use this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Is appleView a local variable, or a class member?   Does anything else alter appleView?

The completion block will run around 1.8 seconds after you start the animation, if appleView is a class member and something changes it you could be removing the wrong thing.  Try capturing appleView[i] in a local variable, like this:

```
UIView *goingAway = appleView[i];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.8 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
       animations:^{
           goingAway.frame = CGRectMake(applePosition, 400.0, 25.0, 25.0);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
           [goingAway removeFromSuperview];
        }];
```